# If a multiplicative set contains zero, then $S^{-1}A$ is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity, and $S\in A$ a multiplicative subset. One then defines the localization of $A$ at $S$,$\,\,S^{-1}A, $ by means of an equivalence relation: $$(a,s)\sim (a',s')\, \Leftrightarrow \exists s_1\in S\,\, \text{such that}\,\, s_1(s'a-sa')=0, \,\, \text{where}\,\,a,a' \in A,\, \text{and}\,\, s,s'\in S.$$

The elements of $S^{-1}A$ are then the equivalence classes, which are usually denoted $a/s.$

In the Algebra book is then stated that if $0\in S, $ then $S^{-1}A$ has precisely one element, namely $0/1.$ (To avoid this trivial case one thus assumes $0\notin S).$ It is  this statement that I dont understand.

Let $0\in S$. Suppose that there exists un equivalence class $a_1/s_1 \in S^{-1}A,  \,\,a_1/s_1\neq 0  \,\,$such that $\exists \,s\in S,\, \, s(s_1a_2-s_2a_1)=0.$ One can distinguish two cases: $1.\,\, s=0, \,\,$ in which case the expression in parenthesis must not be zero. $2.\,\, s\neq0, $ in which case the expression in parenthesis is a zero divisor. I can't go further then this. Can somebody provide the additional steps or give me some hint ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7):

$(a,s)\simeq (0,1)$ since $0(a1-0s)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Directly, without contradiction:

$$\forall\,a\in A\;,\;\;(a,0)\in S^{-1}A\implies\text{ if we take an arbitrary element}\;\;(a',s')\in S^{-1}A$$

then

$$(a',s')=(a',0)\;,\;\;\text{because}\;\;0\cdot(0\cdot a'-s'a')=0\;\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks. I need to show that $(a',0)=(0,1).$  This seems to be the case since: $0\cdot (a'\cdot 1-0\cdot 0)=0.$ But at the same time, $0\cdot(0\cdot 1-a'\cdot 0)=0, \,$ so that also $(1,0) \in S^{-1}A.$ Then, given $0\cdot (1\cdot 1-0\cdot 0)=0, \,\,$ it fallows that $(1,0)=(0,1).$ Is this correct ?

Comment: @user249018 Yes, of course. There's only one element as we've proved that $\;(a,s)\sim (1,0)\;$ , say...with $\;a'=1\;$, or *any* other element $\;a'\in A\;$

Comment: It was to be shown that if $(a',s')\in S^{-1}A,$ then $(a',s')\sim (0,1).$ That's were I got confused with your argument. But if $(1,0)\sim (0,1),\, $this difficulty vanishes. Maybe you could explain one more thing: since one can write the equivalence classes as fractions, does it make sense to write $1/0$ for the equivalece class $(1,0)$ ? In integral rings this is not allowed.

Comment: @user249018 Of course. That we're used to see that as fractions (with the rationals, diadics, etc.) is our problem. The definition is very clear, and if $\;0\in S\;$ then $\;(a,0)\;$ is a legal element of $\;S^{-1}A\;$ . BTW, also for this reason, though not mainly, is that $\;S\;$ is, for any useful application I can think of in comm. algebra right now,  required *not* to contain zero.

Comment: If $a/s \in S^{-1}A$, will it's inverse be $s/a, $ so that one can have $a/s\cdot s/a=1 ?$ The problem is the following: since $s\in S$ then $s\in A, $but $a\in A$ doesn't imply $a\in S$. So, the inverse $s/a$ does not seem to preserve the structure of an element of $S^{-1}A$. What is wrong in my understanding ?

Comment: The inverse of $\;a/s\;$ can exist **iff** $\;s/a\in S^{-1}A\iff a\in S\;$ . This is *usually* not the case. Thus, the ring $\;S^{-1}A\;$ is not, in general, a field, or even a a division ring.

Answer (score 1):

It is a general fact that one can assume, without loss of generality, that $1\in S$. The ring homomorphism $\lambda_S\colon A\to S^{-1}A$ defined by $\lambda_S(a)=a/1$ maps elements of $S$ to invertible elements in $S^{-1}A$.

The zero element in $S^{-1}A$ is $0/1=\lambda_S(0)$. What are the rings in which the zero element is invertible?

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is only the zero ring. Maybe you could explain, what does it mean for the zero element to be invertible ? Also could you elaborate on the following: if $s_1/1, s_1\in S$ is invertible in $S^{-1}A$, then $\exists s_2/1\in S^{-1}A$, such that $s_1/1\cdot s_2/1=(s_1\cdot s_2)/1=1, \,\,$ which I dont understand how. Can you explain this, since $s_1, s_2$ must not be invertible in $S$ ? Thanks.

Comment: @user249018 The ring $S^{-1}A$ is specifically built as an “extension” of $A$ where all elements of $S$ become invertible (it's not generally an overring, but that's the idea). The inverse of $s/1$, for $s\in S$, is obviously $1/s$. The elements of $S^{-1}A$ are of the form $a/s$, where $a\in A$ and $s\in S$.

Comment: What is the preimage, or the inverse image of $1/s$ under $\lambda_S$ ?

Comment: @user249018 It needn’t have one. The map isn’t surjective in general.

Comment: Many thanks. For one more thing though I would like to get your answer: What does  it mean  for the zero element of the zero ring to be invertible ? Anyway it must satisfy the relation: $0 \cdot (0)^{-1}=0 \cdot 0/1=1$! How can this work ? Maybe it is sattled by definition ?

Comment: @user249018 If you assume $0^{-1}$ exists, then $1=0\cdot 0^{-1}=0$, so easily $a=a1=a0=0$, for every $a$.